# Neo4j Cypher: Match Stop At First Match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following paths

```
1->4
1->2->3->4
1->2->3->4->4
```

i want to get what are the best paths for 1->4

the expected result is

```
1->4 
1->2->3->4
without the 1->2->3->4->4)
```

query example:

```
match path =  ((p0 { PositionId : 1})-[r*]->( next {PositionId : 4}))
return extract(z IN nodes(path) | z.PositionId),count(*)
```

Comment: I gather that by "best path" you can't mean shortest path or cheapest path, since you say that `1->4` and `1->2->3->4` are both expected results. So what does "best path" mean and what is it about `1->2->3->4->4` that excludes it?

Comment: @jaderberg - i am trying to show all possible routes to "4" from "1". the problem with "1->2->3->4->4" is that the route is supposed to end at the 4th node.. (without continuing in a loop back to itself)

Comment: That's precisely what Michaels query does. It makes sure that the node `(next {PositionId:4})` is not in the middle of the path, which means that paths that go 'through' or 'past' `next` are excluded, i.e. only paths stopping at the first occurrence of `{PositionId:4}` are included.

Comment: @jaderberg - you are correct. but i want all the data of that path to be summed into the 1->2->3->4. (count(*)) (by doing Michael's solution i am simply ignore that path..)

Comment: Actually, I just tried Michael's query and it didn't filter the paths the way I thought. Don't know why and can't fiddle with it right now, but `WHERE NONE (x in nodes(path)[1..-1] WHERE x = next)` seems to do what I expected–to my mind they ought to be equivalent, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: yeah. any idea? or will i have to do it myself? basically i simply want it to stop once it finds the desired node for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

```
match path =  (p0 { PositionId : 1})-[r*]->( next {PositionId : 4})
WHERE NOT next in nodes(path)[1..-1]
return extract(z IN nodes(path) | z.PositionId),count(*)
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your response.
I have tested it without luck..
Keep in mind that the following path (1->2->3->2->3->4) is still valid

Keep in mind that 4 is a property (and not the ID). i am then doing a group by by that property (PositionId)